# Why do you gain more reputation from upvotes than you lose from downvotes?

Tags: support, reputation, downvotes, upvotes

Why, when your post is downvoted, do you lose 4 reputation, compared to when it was upvoted, where you gain 10? This would mean you could have 0 score on your question/answer, but have gained 12 reputation from it (2 up, 2 down).